# Why is my form is not posting with jQuery .submit()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a system where users are allowed to add books to their library. I am using a jquery UI dialog box and have inserted about 20 rows into the database using the first half of this script.

However, as I was adding in the second half all of a sudden the post information is not showing up on the posted page and I am completely lost as to why.

This was supposed to be a quick addition that's turned into a headache.

**FORM:**

```
<form id="addbookform" action="../models/Books/addBook_submit.cfm" method="POST">
<div style="display: none;" id="addBook" title="Add a Book to Your Library">
    <input type="hidden" id="InputType" name="InputType" value="Add"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="bookempID" name="bookempID"/>

    <label class="labelstyle" >ISBN:</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="17" id="ISBN" name="ISBN">

    <label class="labelstyle" >Title:</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="100" size="50" id="Title" name="Title">*

    <label class="labelstyle">Author's First Name:    </label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="50" id="AFName" name="AFName">

    <label class="labelstyle">Author's Middle Name:</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="50" id="AMName" name="AMName">

    <label class="labelstyle">Author's Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" maxlength="50" id="ALName" name="ALName">*

    <label class="labelstyle">Date Read:</label>
    <input type="text" id="DateRead" name="DateRead">
</div>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function addBook() {
  $("#addBook").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    width: ($(document).width()*.55),
    height: ($(document).height()*.7),
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
              "Add Book": function() {
                          //checkBook();
                          $('#addbookform').submit();
                          },
              Cancel: function() { $(this).dialog("close"); }
    }
  });
}
```

The above piece was working before I started building `checkBook()`. However, now it's no longer working.

Edit:

The form is initiated by:
`<input type="button" class="buttonstyle" value="Add Book" onclick="addBook()" />`
(this works)

Comment: And did you look at the console for errors?

Comment: And what is `checkbook`?

Comment: @epascarello Yes. There were none. Sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: @gdoron it's a longer script makes an ajax call to check if the book is already stored in the system by another user. This piece is not getting there, yet worked before I started making it and doesn't work now, **even when** I comment out the call and all of `function checkBook()`. I did not post it because it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your form must be "visible" in order for the elements to be posted. jQuery can certainly see and access all of the elements regardless of css Display type, but I believe the "submit" action requires the elements that are getting posted to the server be visible. I noticed all the form elements you are attempting to submit are inside of a DIV element with the css property of Display:none;

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are binding a submit event to the form somewhere else in the code.

So, you can try submitting the form without jQuery.

```js
$('#addbookform')[0].submit();
```

Or unbind any event that might be in the form.

```js
$('#addbookform').off().submit();
```